# Prove that the relation on sets $\preceq$ is reflexive and transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that the relation on sets $\preceq$ is reflexive and transitive.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. We write $X \preceq Y$ if there is an injection.

$$f : X \to Y$$

It's reflexive because $f:X \to X$

$\forall x \in X \lvert f(x)=x$

It's transitive because $f:X \to Y$ and $f:Y \to Z \implies f:X \to Z$

$\forall x \in X \ \exists y \in Y \ \lvert  \ f(x)=y$

$\forall y \in Y \ \exists z \in Z \ \lvert  \ f(y)=z$

$\forall x \in X \ \exists z \in Z \ \lvert  \ f(f(x))=z$
Q.E.D

I am not confident that the above proof is totally correct, please give me

some suggestions. thanks.

Comment: For starters, while proving transitivity, your functions should be different. Also depending on the level of details required, you maybe expected to prove that the composition of two injective functions is itself injective. In your attempt, you have not taken into consideration the injectivity of the functions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes $\preceq$ is reflexive due to the identity map being injective. Even though it's trivial, it's probably worth showing briefly that it is in fact injective.

As for transitivity, there are some problems. You want to prove,
$$A \preceq B \text{ and } B \preceq C \implies A \preceq C.$$
If you have sets $A, B, C$ satisfying $A \preceq B$ and $B \preceq C$, then that gives you two injective maps
$$f : A \rightarrow B$$
$$g : B \rightarrow C.$$
(Note that we must use different letters, as they are different functions!) It's your job to create a new function from $A$ to $C$ that is also injective (and to prove it). Using $f$ and $g$ will definitely help!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I will denotate the relation by $\mathcal{R}$.

You have a good idea, however, you need to improve your writing. To see that the relation is reflexive, you need to prove that $_X\mathcal{R}_X$ for every set $X$. We see that the identity function $id_X:X \to X$ given by $$id_X(x)=x$$ is clearly injective, so the reflexivity follows.

Now, let $X,Y,Z$ be sets such that the functions $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to Z$ are injective. Then the function $g \circ f:X \to Z$ is also injective (the operator $\circ$ denotates the composition of functions, i.e. $(g \circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$).

To prove this we let $x,y \in X$ such that $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$. Sice $g$ is inyective we have $f(x)=f(y)$; and since $f$ is also injective we have $x=y$. So $g \circ f$ is injective.

We have proved that if $_X \mathcal{R} _Y$ and $_Y \mathcal{R} _Z$ then $_X \mathcal{R}_Z$. In other words, we have proved that $\mathcal{R}$ is a transitive relation.